# Using jQuery Knob as degree range input

Tags: jquery-knob

I want to let my user input a range of degrees in a nice UI. i.e. something like 45-135 (which, in my app, actually means NE-SE wind direction...). Found jQuery Knob, but not sure how to use it to allow the value to be a range.

Any idea?

Comment: wow, really cool library!

Answer (score 0):

You could put a min and max values of 0 and 360.
Like this:

```
$(".dial").knob({min':0,'max':360});
```

You could even use some steps to limit possible values to some thing corresponding to N-NE-E-SE-S-SO-O-NO

I hope this helps, sorry if not.